# Is it possible to have three stable liquid phases in a binary mixture?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, phase-diagram

With this system, it would be possible to have three liquid phases and two liquid-liquid coexistence regions at various compositions. Similar behaviour is common for solids such as alloys, sometimes with even more stable phases.

I have been searching for a liquid mixture with this behaviour, but haven't found any. Are there any liquid binary mixtures which exhibit this behaviour, or is there any physical reason why this isn't possible? Does it have something to to with the higher disorder liquids have compared to solids?

Comment: I've never seen one on a 'normal' binary phase diagram - miscibility gaps exist for sure but there are not ordered liquid phases. However, liquid crystals do show triple points.